# tensorflow cifar10 example output shape of each step

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning

Could anyone help me to calculate each step output of cifar10 example of tensorflow?
The input image size is 24*24. But in max pooling step, the kernel size is 3 and stride is 2, so (24-3)/2+1 is not integer. What is wrong here? I am new in deep learning. Thank you for helping

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This would be useful to look at: [A guide to convolutional arithmetic](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1603.07285v1.pdf)

In your case you would want to use:

[image: formula]

*i* being the input, *k* kernel size, *s* stride, and *o* is the output so:

[image: formula2]

Your answer would be: 11*11

Comment: Thank you so much. I thought it should be integer, it seems that not necessarily to be integer here. I will read the guide.